# Javascript named Module definition

Tags: javascript, module, definition

I have the following code:

```
;(function (name, context, definition) {
  if (typeof define === 'function' && define.amd){ 
      //How to define a named module here with a string ID?? 
   }

})('jsClass', this, function () {
  //jsClass definition
  'use strict';
   var jsClass = function (options) {
   var testString;
   etc....}
   return jsClass; 
 });
```

I am not sure how to define a named module with a string ID. The point is to define it correctly in order to be able to create an instance of the 'jsClass' this way:

```
var obj1 = new jsClass();
```

Thank you in advance for any input.

Comment: Not much clear about "string ID", what do you mean "define a named module with a string ID"?

Comment: using define(); if I give the argument define(definition); I receive an error hinting that my module is anonymous

Comment: define means definition?

Comment: Yes that s how you define a Module

Comment: I misunderstood that, sorry.

Comment: No worries and thx for your input.